# How to retrieve IMDB user reviews using IMDBPY?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, information-retrieval, imdbpy

is it possible retrieve Imdb user reviews using imdbpy?if there is another way please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

No, reviews are not parsed by the IMDbPY library, so if you need them you have to write your own custom scraper

Keep in mind that they are paginated, making them somehow difficult to obtain, and moreover you have to conform to IMDb's terms of service: https://www.imdb.com/conditions